# Updates more than expected

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update registers of my table but the sql sentence updates all registers.

Could you help me with the code?

```
merge into tableA k
using 
( select  p.host, 
          case count(p.nameJob) when 0 then '0' 
                                 else to_char(count(p.nameJob))  
          end count
                    from (      
                                select distinct b.nameJob, a.host
                                from temp a
                                left join emuser.def_job b
                                on a.grpname in (b.node_id) 
                                and  b.application not like '@NOTINCLUDE'
                        ) p   
           group by p.host ) ran
       on  (k.host=ran.host)
when matched then update set countjobsnodegroup = ran.count;
```

Select only shows me 50 registers but update updates all table registers (997)

```
select  p.host, 
          case count(p.nameJob) when 0 then '0' 
                                 else to_char(count(p.nameJob))  
          end count
                    from (      
                                select distinct b.nameJob, a.host
                                from proc_kk a
                                left join emuser.def_job b
                                on a.grpname in (b.node_id) 
                                and  b.application not like '@NOTINCLUDE'
                        ) p   
           group by p.host;
```

Comment: Firstly, you should use just an `UPDATE` statement (not a merge statement) since you are only updating. Secondly, the only way that could update all records is if host only has one value in the entire table. I think there is some kind of misunderstanding here

Comment: If I do select (without update) I get only 50 register but whith these sql sentence I get 997 update and all the table is updated :-(

Comment: Show us your UPDATE and SELECT's too.

Comment: I put select code above. Update code It's already up

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Oracle 12 is what I use

Comment: I suggest you find a particular `host` value that you don't expect to be updated and confirm for sure whether or not it is updated.

Comment: 50 source rows can definitely update 997 targets rows if there are duplicates in the target. is `host` unique in `tablea`? use `select count(*), count(distinct host) from tablea` to find out. Also, next time please put all info in the question, particularly your testing method, and the correct database platform

Comment: select count(distinct host) from tablea --> 1146,1144.  Select p.host from tableA p, proc_kk c where p.host=c.host  --> 50.

Comment: So for `host` values that shouldn't be updated - what value are they updated with? The only way you will solve this is to analyse individual records and work out what it is doing. Pick a host value that should be updated, and a host value that shouldn't and check what they are being updated with.